# What is the best way to address multiple framework dependencies in iOS/XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, dependencies

My company uses the [iOS Universal Framework]: https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework 'Real Framework' model.  Advantages are non-conflicting dependencies, 'tag/branch'- like control, but hassles include:

1. You have to modify XCode by running a script to view the lib's source code
2. You have to re-run the script when you you install an update to XCode
3. Setting up is a pain
4. Rebuilding the entire framework when make source code changes takes a long time

Are there better alternatives?  Apple should make this easier for developers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are alternative ways, but they might not be better for you, ultimately you should choose a way that consume the least amount of your time, especially playing around with Xcode configuration, which sometime can take days to fix those annoying compiler errors.

**Git Submodules**

One approach is (I currently doing this) simply managing them through [`git-submodules`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) + tag/branch. This way, you get the full source code into your project, you can just do a `git submodule update` to bring the library up to date. And of cause, no Xcode dependency.

**CocoaPod**

[CocoaPod](http://cocoapods.org/) is a ruby-like package manager, it itself is actually a ruby gem, so you'll need ruby installed. Once you get cocoapod onto your machine, you create a plain text file called `Podfile` under you project directory and specify your library dependencies in there, then, you issue the `pod install` command to download the libraries **and all their dependencies** onto your machine.

Both methods mentioned above are actually just to create a simpler way of downloading the full library's source code onto you project and keeping them up-to-date. And really, that is the best way (IMO) to manage frameworks in iOS project.